# do 'p & ~p' , '~p & ~~p' equal 'either p or ~p'?

Tags: logic, propositional-logic

In classical logic,

(1) p & ~p is equivalent to (2) ~p & ~~p;

if we read 'p & ~p' as p, ~p are both true/the case, and if we read '~p & ~~p' as p, ~p are both false/not the case (because their negations are true).

Or equivalently: if we read (1) as violating the law of non-contradiction ~(p & ~p) , and (2) as violating the law of excluded middle p or ~p , although they are equivalent in Classical logic notably through DeMorgans Law, there is a subtle difference which becomes even more apparent in non-classical logics, which have, e.g., the law of non-contradiction but not excluded middle.

That is: strictly speaking, the law of excluded middle and its instances have an inclusive disjunction. It is the law of non-contradiction that makes the disjunction of LeM an exclusive one; in classical logic, conversely, strictly speaking, the conjunction ~p & ~~p does not violate the form ~(p & ~p); in classical logic, it is because of the excluded middle p or ~p , that it is equivalent to violating ~(p & ~p).

That being said, it becomes clear that:

Following the convention of reading ' p & ~p' as p,~p being both true/ the case , we should also read is as NOT being both false /not the case, since, strictly speaking, it does not violate p or ~p.

Therefore we should also read ' ~p & ~~p' as p, ~p NOT being both true/the case, since, strictly speaking, it does violate p or ~p (and strictly speaking it does not violate , ~p or ~~p ).

But then since in (1), (2) (which are intersubstitutable according to classical logic) p,~p are ALSO not both the case & not both not the case;
Then we have also either p or ~p , where either/or, is an exclusive disjunction (meaning p,~p are not both the case, but also not both not the case).

But then we have a paradox, since we seem to have ( either p or ~p) = (p & ~p ) (meaning at the same time in the same sense : p,~p are not both the case , neither both not the case, but also both the case , and both not the case);
and according to classical logic (either p or ~p) ≠ (p & ~p).

Because when we apply the same scheme to (3) 'either p or ~p' and (4) 'either ~p or ~~p', we can read (3) as: p,~p are not both the case, neither both not the case. ~(p & ~p) & (p or ~p). We can read the (4) as: p,~p both being not the case is not the case , neither both being not not the case ~(~p & ~~p) & (~p or ~~p).

It is clear to see that (3) and (4) do not violate the law of non-contradiction, neither the law of excluded middle.

But then how can (either p or ~p) = (p & ~p) ?

Comment: On what ground are you asserting that "either p or ~p = p & ~p" ? The first one is TRUE while the second one is FALSE.

Comment: I do know that according to classical logic 'either p or ~p' is a tautology and always true, 'p & ~p' a contradiction and always false but if you read the whole text it should be clear that there seems to be a paradox following the tenets of classical logic if we assume that p & ~p  is equivalent to ~p & ~~p then p & ~p seems to be equal to either p or ~p.  Lets use unconventional thinking skills for a minute ;)

Comment: If you derive a FALSE conclusion, either you have made some mistake in using the logical rules or you have used a FALSE premise in your argument.

Comment: Thats seems to be a false conclusion you have there, since "this statement is false" leads us to the fact that statement (Liar sentence) is true if and only if it is false. using logical rules without false premises ( at least seemingly) which is a FALSE conclusion. We have trouble pointing out faulty application of rules of logic or a faulty premise so that seems to be a counterexample, just like my example above

Comment: I added a lot of punctuation, in an attempt to clarify the rationale. I hope I was able to follow your line of thought.

Comment: Since p & ~p is already a paradox why is it at all surprising that it leads to more paradoxes? And ~(p or ~p) = p & ~p in classical logic, so all those paradoxes are just reiterations of the one assumed.

Comment: Conventionally it is understood as a contradiction , not a paradox

Comment: Paradox is "a seemingly absurd or self-contradictory statement", according to the dictionary. Btw, you should put @username into your comments to notify users they are addressed to.

Comment: @Conifold thanks for the remark, yes a paradox is a piece of seeminly valid & sound  piece of reasoning  that has a contradiction or counterint and non-acceptable conclusion. with 'p & ~p' as premisse it is already clear that according to the rules of classical logic the piece of reasoning clearly cannot be valid neither sound , therefore conventionally it does not qualify as a paradox but just a contradiction, altough with the argument put forward above just from analyzing the form p & ~p  it seems to be a paradox indeed ! so you're not wrong , but it is not conventionally qualified as such

Comment: Contradiction is "counterintuitive and non-acceptable", hence a paradox. Your argument is hard to follow, but contradiction implies anything in classical logic, so there is nothing surprising about its result.

Answer (score 2):

p&~p is equivalent to ~p&~~p, but **p&~p and ~p&~~p are *not* equivalent to pv~p** -- in fact, they are contradictory to each other. This can be easily seen by taking a look at the truth table:

```
p | ~p | ~~p | p&~p | ~p&~~p | pv~p
--|----|-----|------|--------|-----
1 | 0  |  1  |  0   |   0    |  1  
0 | 1  |  0  |  0   |   0    |  1
```

p&~p and ~p&~~p are equivalent to each other and contradictions (= statements that are always false) -- there is no interpretation under which both p and ~p, or both ~p and ~~p, can be true at the same time, hence they have 0 in all rows of the truth table.
pv~p, on the other hand, is a tautology (= a statement that is always true): It is true under every possible interpretation, and correspondingly, in every row of the truth table.

Since p&~p and ~p&~~p have the same truth value in each row, they are logically equivalent.
Since p&~p/~p&~~p and pv~p have different truth values in at least one row, p&~p/~p&~~p are not logically equivalent to pv~p. Since they even have different truth values in all rows, they are not just inequivalent, but contradictory to each other.

Comment: Yes I know that but if 'p & ~p' (which violates the law of non-contradiction BUT NOT the law of excluded middle) is equivalent to '~p & ~~p' (which violates the law of excluded middle BUT NOT the law of non-contradiction) then p,~p seems also to be not both not the case (via the violation of law of non-contradiction), but also not both the case (via violation of excludes middle)  but that follows tge definition of excluded middle , hence we have also either p or ~p , but then p & ~p seems to also express the proposition either p or ~p , hence p&~p= either p or ~p

Comment: ~p&~~p violates the law of non-contradiction.

Comment: not if the law of non-contradiction is stated as ~(p & ~p)  since ~p & ~~p states that p,~p are both NOT the case (they are both false) , while the law of non-contradiction states that they cannot be both the case (they cannot be both true) on the other hand it does violate the law of excluded middle : p or ~p which states that p,~p cannot be both not the case (that they cannot be both false)

Comment: The law of non-contradiction is ~(phi&~phi), for arbitrary instances of formulas phi. ~p&~~p is such an instance with phi=~p that violates this principle.

Comment: In the first comment added in this conversation it should be " ... but that follows the definition of EXCLUSIVE DISJUNCTION (not that of excluded middle)..."

Comment: ... But this doe not in any way change the fact that neither of these are equivalent to pv~p. Look at the truth table  and you got your answer, there's not more to it than that.

Comment: "The law of non-contradiction is ~(phi&~phi), for arbitrary instances of formulas phi. ~p&~~p is such an instance with phi=~p that violates this principle" alright lets go with this one following that definition , the formula ( ~phi & ~~phi ) is not a violation of the law of non-contradiction.  it is one of excludes middle. truth table won't help here , if (~phi & ~~phi) is equivalent to (~phi & phi) then we seem to run in troubles because it leads us to the fact that e.g. phi & ~phi does also express the proposition either phi or ~phi , where 'either/or' = exclusive disjunction

Comment: Read what I wrote. ~p&~~p *is* an instance of phi&~phi (the violation of LNC), namely with phi=~p. There is nothing to argue about that, it's a direct substitution. No, truth tables don't show this, but that's why LNC or LEM are irrelevant to the question of equivalence. If the truth table shoes that the two formulas are not equivalent, then they are not equivalent. Again, there is no way you can argue against that. If you want to do, then you're not longer talking about classical logic.

Comment: the form a.( phi & ~phi)  is the negation of the form b. ~ (phi & ~phi) , but c.(~phi & ~~phi) is NOT the negation of LnC , it is the negation of LeM d.(phi or ~phi).  why? Because (c) states that phi,~phi are both not the case such that it doesn't violate LnC which states that phi,~phi cannot both be the case. but it does violate LeM which states that phi,~phi cannot both fail to be the case.

Comment: LNC -- ~(phi&~phi) -- and LEM -- phiv~phi -- are formula *schemes* -- they are patterns with variables for formulas (here: phi) that stand for infinitely many concrete instances of this pattern. A formula is an instance of a formula scheme if there is a way of inserting concrete formulas into the variables such that you end up with the putative formula instance.

Comment: Again: Read what I wrote. I never said that ~p&~~p is the negation of LNC. I said that it is an *instance* of the negation of LNC, as proven by inserting ~p for phi. On the other hand, ~p&~~p is *not* an instance of LEM, since there is no way of substituting the variable phi in phiv~phi for a concrete formula such that you end up with ~p&~~p. One is a disjunction, the other a conjunction, so there is no way one can be an instance of the other.

Comment: And again: All that is totally irrelevant to the question of whether or not ~p&~~p and pv~p are equivalent. The truth table *proves* that they are not equivalent, that's just how classical logic works. Anything else one could possibly claim can only be wrong. That's all I have to say about this discussion, I can only repeat myself at this point.

Comment: ~(p & ~p) is an instance of LnC , (p or ~p) is an instance of LeM we can agree on that,  now (p & ~p) would be a violation of LnC , but not of LeM. since the conjunction of p,~p  does not violate the (inclusive) disjunction of p,~p. In the same way a formula can be constructed such that it violates LnC but not LeM , but since they are equivalent in classical logic, one tends to forget the difference between the two

Comment: For a matter of fact suppose that p is a simple formula (meaning there are no connectives, it is not composed of other formulae) then according to classical logic ~p is also a formula (namely its negation)  but then between (p & ~p) , (~p & ~~p)  one of the formulae violates only LnC and the other one only LeM ! namely (p & ~p) violates LnC ,  but (~p & ~~p) does only violate LeM ! since they are equivalent in classical logic,  together they do violate LnC & LeM.